# Compound primary key in Table type variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables, primary-key, table-variable

SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(
    PersonID INT NOT NULL,
    Person2ID INT NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(100),
CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PersonID, Person2ID)
);
```

Gives:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONSTRAINT'.
```

Is there any way to have compound Primary key in Table valued variables?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can define a composite primary key like this:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(   
    PersonID INT NOT NULL,    
    Person2ID INT NOT NULL,    
    Description NVARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (PersonID, Person2ID)
);
```